# why I can update state of an Object extend immutable trait in scala

Tags: scala

I created a class extend scala.Immutable

```
  class SomeThing(var string: String) extends Immutable {
      override def toString: String = string
  }
```

As I expected, scala compiler should help me prevent change state of class SomeThing. But when I run this test

```
  "Test change state of immutable interface" should "not allow" in {
     val someThing = new SomeThing("hello")
     someThing.string = "hello 1"
     println(someThing)
  }
```

The result is `hello 1` and scala compiler don't throw any warning or error.

Why they have to add Immutable trait without help us prevent object mutable?

Comment: If you want to prevent mutation of a variable, just make it a `val` instead of a `var` - that will generate the compile warning you want. Regarding [**scala.Immutable**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Immutable.html) I have never seen it before, but it seems is just a plain trait that is used internally by the scala library to differentiate between _Immutable_ VS _Mutable_ data structures _(like the collections)_, I don't think it is intended to be used by client code.

Comment: The documentation says that it is a *marker trait*. So, the trait exists so that *you* can tell *others* that this data structure is immutable. In your case, you simply lied about it. There's nothing the compiler can do if you lie to it. Note that it is simply impossible for the compiler to check whether a data structure is immutable or not, in fact, this is known to be equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: I've opened a scala/bug ticket suggesting the trait be deprecated and eventually removed from the standard library: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11353

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several aspects to this question.

**1.** A simple one is that Scala compiler can't really ensure immutability for many various reasons. For example, the main target platform JVM allows modifying even `final` fields using reflection. Another reason this is not enforceable is code like this

```
 /////////////////////////////////////////
 //// library v1
 package library

 class LibraryData(val value:Int)


 /////////////////////////////////////////
 //// code that uses the library
 package app

 class UserData(val data:LibraryData) extends Immutable



 /////////////////////////////////////////
 //// library v2
 package library

 class LibraryData(var value:Int) //now change it to var!
```

Since the "library" is compiled independently of the "app" and doesn't even know about existence of the "app" there is no point in time where compiler can catch the broken contract.

**2.** More fundamental misunderstanding you seem to have is what `trait` does. In this context `trait` (or "`interface`" in some other languages) represents a ***contract*** between the implementation and the user-code about how the implementation can and should behave. However not every kind of a contract can be represented as a `trait` (at least without making the code super-complicated). For example, for a mutable collection there is a contract that `size` should return the number of times `add` (or `+=`) has been called but there is no way to represent such a contract as a `trait` besides declaring that there are methods `size` and `+=` with corresponding signatures. On the other hand, for most of the contracts there is no way to enforce implementation to follow the contract . For example, an implementation of `size` that always returns `0` technically matches all the types but is clearly breaking the contract.

Similarly `Immutable` doc says:

> A marker trait for all immutable data structures such as immutable collections.

So it is just a marker `trait` which is one of the ways to work around contracts that can't be really represented as types. And it says that whoever implements that trait ***claims*** to be an immutable object. Your code claims that but clearly breaks the contract. So technically it is your fault for not respecting the contract.